# A bash command that adds newlines to *.cpp and *.h (or any specified filetypes)?

Tags: bash, append, echo, newline

I tried running

```
echo "\n" >> *.cpp *.h
```

But I got

```
*.cpp: Ambiguous.
```

A simple command would do, but added bonus if it only adds it to non-empty files that don't end with newline already

Comment: `find . -iname '*.cpp' -o -iname '*.h' -exec sh -xc 'echo >> "{}"' \;`, perhaps. Note that the `"\n"` makes `echo` print *two* newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't win any beauty awards, but it's explicit and functional at least, and matches the requirements exactly (only adds newlines to files that are not empty and that do not end with a newline):

```
for f in *.cpp *.h; do
    if [[ $(tail -c1 "$f"; echo x) =~ [^$'\n']x ]]; then
        echo >> "$f"
    fi
done
```

Explanation:

- `tail -c1 "$f"` outputs the last character from the file, if any.
- `echo x` is a hack to make sure newlines are kept. (Trailing newlines are deleted from `$()` command substitutions.)
- `=~` compares against the regular expression `[^\n]x`, i.e., some character (there must be a character) that isn't a newline followed by `x`. We need `$'\n'` (a bashism) instead of `\n` to match a literal newline.
- `echo >> "$f"` adds a newline to the end of a file. (`echo` will print a terminating newline unless the `-n`  flag is used.)

**Update:**

Here's a simpler version:

```
for f in *.cpp *.h; do
    if tail -c1 "$f" | egrep -q .; then
        echo >> "$f"
    fi
done
```

`egrep` matches line-by-line, and so won't match against a newline. The regular expression `.` will therefore match any character (and there must be a character) that isn't a newline. (`if` on a pipeline checks the exit status of the last command in the pipeline -- `egrep` in this case. `-q` makes `egrep` silent.)

Comment: Hmm, perhaps `wc -l` could be used to simplify this too. I just noticed it counts newlines.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are attempting is to ensure that every file ends with a newline character (as opposed to ending with a single blank line), then you could do this with either GNU or BSD `sed` (Posix standard sed doesn't have to recognize the `-i` option, but most do):

```
sed -n -i.bak 'G;P' *.{cc,h}
```

The `-n` option suppresses automatic printing. `-i.bak` edits in place, keeping a backup file with the `.bak` extension. (If you don't want the backup file, supply an empty string as the extension.)

The program:

```
G  append a newline and the hold buffer (which is empty)
P  print the pattern space up to the first newline.
```

Comment: Was waiting for a `sed` version. :)